# Check the file name using pattern or regular expression matching in python

Tags: python, regex

How I can check the certain file naming style using the regular expression?

Example: `FOO_FILENAME.cnf.FILENAME`

Here I want to compare file name with this pattern `FOO*.cnf.*`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `re.match`

```
>>> s = 'FOO_FILENAME.cnf.FILENAME'
>>> re.match(r'FOO.*\.cnf\..*', s)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 25), match='FOO_FILENAME.cnf.FILENAME'>
```

Comment: use glob `glob.glob('FOO*.cnf.*')`